# How do I handle uppercase JSON field names in my lowercase model

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm new to Angular and just started my first project with Angular 6. I have a REST API that provides my app with data. The service and my app are communicating as the results are output to the console as expected. The problem is Angular's automagical property mapping is failing; the field names in the JSON are all UPPERCASE and the property names in my model are not. How do I force the mapping to be case-insensitive OR manually create the field map?

JSON from REST API:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 123456,
        "LOCATION_LISTING": "Place of Origin",
        "SCIENTIFIC_NAME": "Gavia Immer"
    }
]
```

Angular model:

```
export interface IThing {
  id: number;
  location_listing: string;
  scientific_name: string;
}
```

Comment: can you post example json and model schema ?

Answer (score 3):

Accessing a JavaScript object property by the property name is case-sensitive. You either have to mutate the results or rename the properties on the `IThing` interface so they are uppercase. I recommend you just make them uppercase. So that what you see in the browser's network panel matches what you see in the source code.

```
export interface IThing {
   ID: number;
   LOCATION_LISTING: string;
   SCIENTIFIC_NAME: string;
}

this.http.get<IThing[]>(...);
```

If you *really* want them lowercase. You'll need to mutate the results so that the keys are lowercase.

```
this.http.get<IThing[]>(...)
    .pipe(map((things) => {
        return things.map((thing)=> {
            const obj = {};
            Object.keys(thing).forEach((key)=>obj[key.toLowerCase()]=thing[key]);
            return obj;
        });
    });
```